# What is the point of CSS Frameworks?

Tags: html, css

What is the point of these CSS Frameworks? I don't understand them. When I look at them, all I see is boring layouts that seem overbearingly-difficult to adapt to your own unique designs.

Is this the case, or am I just missing something here? I'm referring to (frameworks in general) things like Blueprint, Less, Skeleton, 960 Grid system, Base, Gridless, etc etc etc.

I know this is a really simple thing but I just don't get it. I have searched but have not found anything that helps me to understand what the big deal is. When I look at their code, all I see is mess. Weird class and id names *all over the place*.

(This isn't a rant or complaint by the way, I just really don't get it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> CSS frameworks are pre-prepared software frameworks that are meant to
> allow for easier, more standards-compliant web design using the
> Cascading Style Sheets language. Most of these frameworks contain at
> least a grid. More functional frameworks also come with more features
> and additional JavaScript based functions, but mostly design
> orientated and unobtrusive. This differentiates these from functional
> and full JavaScript frameworks. -[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_frameworks)

***Advantages***

> - **They can help you learn CSS**. You might just literally not know how to    pull off a solid multi-column layout. A framework may be a
>   good place    to get your feet wet understanding how CSS works.
> - **They provide code that you just don't need to write from scratch every time**, like    resets. I've long been a proponent that the star
>   selector (*)    margin/padding reset is a fine reset. I use it all the
>   time. But...    if you are starting a major new project that is going
>   to be loads of    pages, live for years and years, and will grow over
>   time, you should    invest right away in a more robust reset. All
>   these frameworks start    with brilliant resets that cover all the
>   bases and will have you    covered for years to come.
> - **They relieve cross-browser concerns**. You    can't undervalue this. We've all felt the burn of finding out our    sites are borked
>   in some browser or another at a hugely inopportune    time. Frameworks
>   are built to bring their magic to all browsers.
> - **It helps you build good habits**. Like including a print stylesheet in    your projects. I always intend to build one, and I
>   often do, but the    chances are a lot higher that I do it if I have
>   one there from the    get-go.
> - **They encourage grid based design**. Which is a good thing.    Grids don't mean boring! They just help you achieve better
>   readability, scanability, balance visual weight, flexibity,
>   expandability, and just overall page page cohesiveness.
> - **They come with documentation**. If you need help getting started, framework    generally come with some support files. This can be
>   particularly nice    if you are designing a site you will be handing
>   off to a client. You    can just let them know what framework you used
>   and refer them to that    documentation for support requests.
> - **They lay groundwork**. If you are using something like YUI, your life will be a lot easier if you use    All-YUI-Stuff-All-The-Time.
>   It's built to work together and built for    expandability.
>
> [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-css-framework/)

Also see: [Comparison of CSS frameworks](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html?v=2.0)

Comment: Why do you quote and reference Wikipedia, but not [the rest of your answer](http://css-tricks.com/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-css-framework)?

Comment: It's there. I was formatting the answer. Give some time.

Comment: That's not an excuse. You quoted Wikipedia as appropriate in your original revision, and had ample time to do so with the other source. It was only after I commented that you edited the link in. Always remember to cite your sources. Don't wait for someone to flag or comment on your post for plagiarism before you will act on it.

Comment: OK. Should I delete the answer? Or put only bold points without explanation?

Comment: You simply should have added reference at first place. :)

Comment: You don't have to delete your answer, but see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing - it encourages you to use your own words rather than make your answers consist almost entirely of quotations.